# why is my project euler #4 program not working?

Tags: python

I am trying to answer the following problem
A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

My code is:

```
for factorOne in range(100,1000):

    for factorTwo in range(100,1000):
        testNo = str(factorOne * factorTwo)
        listNo = list(testNo)
        length =len(listNo)

        for callingNo in range(0,length):

            if listNo[callingNo] == listNo[(length - 1) - callingNo]:
                tempSol = int(testNo)
                finalSol = 0

                if tempSol > finalSol:
                    finalSol = tempSol

print(finalSol)
```

I only have a basic knowledge of python since I have only been learning it for about two weeks, which is about 10 hours with the lessons I get.
It gave me the answer 990009,I am not entirely sure why and other people's solutions were too complicated for me to understand. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error lies in the method you are using to check if a number is a palindrome. Once you have generated your product of factorOne * factorTwo * factorThree, you can simply use slicing to check if it is a palindrome.

```
>>> a = '90009'
>>> a == a[::-1]
True

>>> b = '999000'
>>> b == b[::-1]
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are testing your palindromes incorrectly. You are only ever testing one digit at a time, and if that one digit matches its 'mirror' you declare it a palindrome.

Your highest number, for example, has the first and last digit matching. That means your `if` test in the first iteration is `True` before you tested *all* digits.

Because Python makes it trivial to reverse a string, all you have to do is test `testNo` against its reverse:

```
if testNo == testNo[::-1]:
    # palindromic
```

This tests **all** digits before declaring the number palindromic.

With this approach the number is quickly found:

```
>>> found = 0
>>> for i in range(100, 1000):
...     for j in range(100, 1000):
...         candidate = i * j
...         if str(candidate) == str(candidate)[::-1] and candidate > found:
...             found = candidate
... 
>>> found
906609
```

or, using `max()`, a generator expression and `itertools.product()`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> max(i * j for i, j in product(range(100, 1000), repeat=2) if str(i * j) == str(i * j)[::-1])
906609
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for callingNo in range(0,length):
    if listNo[callingNo] == listNo[(length - 1) - callingNo]:
        # solved
```

The effect of this loop and test is to declare success as soon as the check of the first two digits passes. If the first digit matches the last digit, that's it, solution found.

You need to change the logic so it checks *all* the digits before declaring success. In other words, reverse the `if` test: if the test *fails*, then you know you do not have a solution. If it *passes*, you have a *potential* solution, but you need to keep checking.